# How to split and trim a string in one line

Tags: vb.net, linq, split

I want to Split a string and then Trim the results in one single line.
So the string:

```
 "psychology ¦ history ¦ geography"
```

should return the following members without trailing or leading spaces:

```
psychology
history
geography
```

I've tried:

```
String.Split("¦").Trim
```

but `Trim` does not work for arrays. Is there a one-line method, no matter how dirty, that does this job?

I'm sure this has been duped many times but I couldn't find the relevant solution for `VB.Net`. Please don't just link to a question in another language without explaining how I can convert the solution to `VB.Net`.

Comment: Slow down a bit, don't ask for one-liners when you are still struggling with basic syntax.  There is a For-Next loop after this Split call, that's where Trim belongs.

Comment: @HansPassant - I'm not struggling with basic syntax, I know how to do a For Next loop to do exactly this. I'm just looking for a one-line solution because I like them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Split);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Trim);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) your string in one line using the LINQ's [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

Both assigning the string to a local variable:

```
Dim input As String = "psychology ¦ history ¦ geography"
Dim result1 = input.Split("¦"c).Select((Function(s) s.Trim))
```

Or directly using the string as source:

```
Dim result2 = "psychology ¦ history ¦ geography".Split("¦"c).Select((Function(s) s.Trim))
```

Note that the `Type` of `result1` and `result2` is now an [IEnumerable(Of String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1), not an array:
LINQ's methods return a `IEnumerable<T>` if not otherwise instructed.
Also note that this syntax supposes that [`Option Infer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-infer-statement) is `On`. If you keep it `Off`, you need to declare the type explicitly:

```
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of String) = (...)
```

If you need a string Array as output, you need to ask:

```
Dim result3 As String() = input.Split("¦"c).Select((Function(s) s.Trim)).ToArray()
```

*About the Type Characters (`c`) appended to the `Split` method parameter*:

[From the Visual Basic Language Reference: Char Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/char-data-type?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vb.Char)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396)

> **Type Characters**. Appending the literal type character `C` to a
>   single-character string literal forces it to the `Char` data type. `Char`
>   has no identifier type character.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have embedded spaces in the items, you can just pass the space character as a separator as well as pipe.  Combine that with the remove empty entries option and multiple space separators aren't an issue.  If you need to handle other whitespace characters, you can add those.

`input.Split(New String() {"|", " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`